# Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to access the dao instance of my room database which is being used to store names(This code I wrote just to get familiar to jetpack compose).

I tried to access my dao instance inside my composable function but is giving me this error -> Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun  remember(calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)

My Code

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavController){
 var dao by remember{
     mutableStateOf(NameDatabase.getInstance(LocalContext.current).getDao())
 }
 var scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
 var username by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf("") }
 Column(
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
     horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
 ){
     OutlinedTextField(value = username, onValueChange = {username=it})
     Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
     Button(onClick = {
         navController.navigate("showScreen/$username")

     }) {
         Text("Submit")
     }
 }
}
```

I am getting the error on this line
`mutableStateOf(NameDatabase.getInstance(LocalContext.current).getDao())`

Specifically `LocalContext.current` is giving this error.

PS: I have resolved this error but want to know what is the meaning of this error any why I can't get the dao instance inside remember.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`LocalContext.current` is marked with `@Composable` and can only be used inside another `@Composable` function. `remember` lambda is marked with `@DisallowComposableCalls`, and from the name, you can understand that it disallows composable calls. So it's not related to `mutableStateOf`, only to `remember`.

You can face same issue with side effects, like `LaunchedEffect`, or event callbacks, like `clickable` - in these cases, there's no `@DisallowComposableCalls` because these are not inlined functions, and callbacks are gonna be called onside of `@Composable` scope.

You need to read the value outside of the function:

```kotlin
val context = LocalContext.current
var dao by remember {
    mutableStateOf(NameDatabase.getInstance(context).getDao())
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some source or document describing about why does context cannot be obtained inside mutableStateOf()?

Comment: How to use `LaunchedEffect`?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky With `LaunchedEffect` you can use the same technique: define  `val context = LocalContext.current` before using `LaunchedEffect`, and then you can use in the block